# How to setup scriptalias, alias in vagrant/puppet for apache/nginx?

Tags: apache, vagrant, yaml, puppet, puphpet

I needed to setup scriptalias for my vagrant machine for apache in puppet yaml configuration, but could not find a way to do it, without using buildin predefined cgi-bin scriptalias name. I found question elsewhere on google, but it was not replied.

try with usual approach

```
scriptalias: pma vendor/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmim
```

resulted in

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ pma vendor/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

which was not satisfactory

Comment: Thank you for minus point when there is only one question of it's kind, and got up-vote and praise comment by creator of the puphpet.com tool itself  -  must be accidentally at the same time I was publicly speaking being happy about reputation increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to reply it as at the same time i found the answer after few days,
after studying vagrant template _aliases.erb, i found out it must be setup as yaml array in vhost configuration

```
    servername:
    aliases:
        -
            aliasmatch: /pma(.*)
            path: ./phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin$1
      # -
      #     alias:  /pma 
      #     path: ./phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      # -
      #     alias:  /pma/themes
      #     path: ./phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/themes
```

it is also good to setup executing of that directory by php-fpm as it is usually the case for vagrant apache

```
directories:
                avd_p60e0bzgan4a:
                    path: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_5xnjfunw9aia:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: ''
                            provider: filesmatch
```

Comment: I wish all users were like you :)

Comment: wow, it is my honour to have comment from you Juan :), thank you, i wish all programmers would be like you bringing amazing tools, making work fluently perfect.